# Ajaxtoolkit downloaded for each page

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We have a SharePoint Solution that uses the Microsoft Ajaxtoolkit.

I am doing some performance testing and see that the javascript is being downloaded for each page, causing some page to download more than 1 MB.

The type of call that is being made is:

```
http://serverName/ScriptResource.axd?d=aMbl7-5dNZOmlggsdXNoTVIFa6esvsBgC6BHXX0EL95-pM5lSDjyY8ReL2JvKluJzYr9etKytxzEbXXTRh-bMV2x_m8iGd7S727g4aeKATA1&t=5aa0b262
```

The file that this is being returned by the above is MicrosoftAjax.debug.js.

Is there a way to avoid the javascript being downloaded for each page?

Comment: I can only presume that in production, you won't be including the debug library? - 1Mb seems very excessive for a single JS Lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the release library, not the debug one.

See [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/debugging-ajax-using-microsoft-ajax-library-internet-explorer-and-mozilla-firefox) on MicrosoftAjax.debug.js:

> Once the development stage is
>   finished, you can switch your
>   application to the release version of
>   the script (MicrosoftAjax.js), which
>   is smaller and doesn’t contain the
>   debugging features presented above.